# How to get exactly real current date

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, cocos2d-iphone

I know you guys might be saying that this question is very common but actually I'm referring to the actual current date and time:

Let say today is 1st of August,12pm and no matter how the user change their phone date and time, I will still know today is 1st of August, 12pm...

Anyone know how can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can get the real date and time from an [NTP server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol), but this assumes that you have internet access.

Answer (score 1):

If the user changes their phone date and time, then you will get that date and time... since NSDate gets its value from the `iOS.` If you want it to return the actual time per time zone, you will have to set up a small `Web Service` or something that returns the time for that particular time zone.

Answer (score -1):

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
```

Now `currentDate` will have the current date & time when this code is executed.

Comment: NSDate will just return the current phone date and time. If i change the phone date and time, then the returned date and time will not be the accurate one.

Comment: My best bet would be that you sync up with a web service which returns the exact time and date and use that for your app.